# Angular: Can't Get Updated Data out of Singleton Service Instance

Tags: angular, singleton

**Note:** Using Angular 10.2, Node 12.16.3

**Backgound:**
I have an Authentication Service declared as a singleton in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
--> AuthService, 
    HouseService,
...
```

To keep my question simple, I just need a local variable in the Authentication Service to be updated and available to downrange services.

**Problem:**
Every attempt & approach by other components (i.e. `NavbarComponent`) to access this data returns only how it was first initialized.

**Attempted Solutions:**

1. Seemed like an Service instancing problem, but code above should indicate that the Authentication Service is a singleton for the entire module.
2. Per another StackOverflow post, I added the `--aot` to the ng build command.
3. Per other StackOverflow posts, I attempted to employ a `BehaviorSubject` where a basic message (string) is updated after the login message is called:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  ...
  messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('ORIGINAL MESSAGE');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  ...
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    console.log("Authentication Service: changeMessage called with: " + message);
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }
  ...
  public login(modelUsername: any, modelPassword: any) {
    console.log("Authentication Service: Updating message via changeMessage...");            
    this.changeMessage("UPDATED MESSAGE VALUE");
  }
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  ...
  message:string;
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.currentMessage.subscribe(newMessage => {
      console.log("NavbarComponent : Update event captured: new message=" + newMessage);
      this.message = newMessage;
      console.log("NavbarComponent : Message value is now=" + newMessage);
    })
    ...
  }
```

**Current (console) results:**
If I remove the call to `changeMessage(...)` in `login()`, the component is notified of a change (though I think this is mainly the event for initialization):

```
ComponentA: Update event captured: new message=ORIGINAL MESSAGE
ComponentA: Message value is now=ORIGINAL MESSAGE
```

If I leave in the call to `changeMessage(...)`, I now see the (expected) messages that a change is being made; however, my receiving function for the `BehaviorSubject` is the **OLD** value.

```
Authentication Service: Updating message via changeMessage...
Authentication Service: changeMessage called with: UPDATED MESSAGE VALUE
ComponentA: Update event captured: new message=ORIGINAL MESSAGE
ComponentA: Message value is now=ORIGINAL MESSAGE
```

I've spent several days on this so any suggestions and/or guidance is greatly appreciated.

**More details based upon comments**

1. The (app)/home/login-form component calls AuthenticationService.login():

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = false;

    this.authSrv.login(this.modelUsername, this.modelPassword).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      },
...
```

For the purposes of testing, the login method now only calls *changeMessage(...)* to no avail.

2. Updated top-level note to reflect Node version (12.16.3)

Comment: I just created a quick mockup of this with the setup you explained and it works as it should. I put a login button in the AppComponent that calls the AuthService login method and in the NavBar component I get the updated message. There is something else going on here that isn't in the code you are showing.

Comment: I added a static ID and logging statement to the Authentication Service. The instance that is doing the login is different than the instance being asked for the data. In other words, I'm not getting a singleton instance as I expect. But I'm perplexed as I declared it as a provider in the top-level app.module.ts.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't in the providers array in another module?

Comment: Thank you!!! That nudge was it! I did have an extra reference in the login form's providers array to the Authentication Service...something leftover from when the project started. Can't thank you enough, Mr. Alderson!!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the above comment, the issue was an extra reference to the Authentication Service in a lower-level component (not just in the app.module.ts). Credit goes to Andrew Alderson for the nudge to check!!!